# Enumerated list across table

Tags: tables, enumerate

I want to have an enumerated list inside a table, but with varying numbers of items in each cell, appearing like this:[image]

This sort of works, but it's of course not enumerating

```
\begin{tabular}{| p{.45\textwidth} | p{.45\textwidth} |}
\hline
Column 1 Heading & Column 2 Heading \\
\hline
1. Item 1 & 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.. \\
                   & 3. More and more lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. \\
\hline
4. Perhaps this text could go on for a while too & 5. Item 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `resume*` option form the `enumitem` package in order to get a continued numering even in separate `enumerate` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| p{.45\textwidth} | p{.45\textwidth} |}
\hline
Column 1 Heading & Column 2 Heading \\
\hline
\begin{enumerate}[series=table,nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}] \item Item 1\end{enumerate} &
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=table] \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.. 
                  \item More and more lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. \end{enumerate}\\
\hline
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=table] \item Perhaps this text could go on for a while too \end{enumerate} & 
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=table] \item Item 5 \end{enumerate}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The following MWE contains some improvements concerning the general table layout. With the `tabularx` package, you could spread the table columns evenly, so that the whole table is exactly as wide as the textwidth. Getting rid of the vertical lines and replacing the `\hline` commands with the appropriate rules from the `booktabs` package gives the table a more open look:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\toprule
Column 1 Heading & Column 2 Heading \\
\midrule
\begin{enumerate}[series=table,nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}] \item Item 1\end{enumerate} &
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=table] \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.. 
                  \item More and more lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. \end{enumerate}\\
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=table] \item Perhaps this text could go on for a while too \end{enumerate} & 
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=table] \item Item 5 \end{enumerate}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use this style of table more often throughout your document, you might also be interested in globally defining a new environment that already contains all the layout arguments. This can be done with the help of `\newlist` and `\setlist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlist{tabenumi}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumi]{label={\arabic*.},nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\toprule
Column 1 Heading & Column 2 Heading \\
\midrule
\begin{tabenumi}[series=table] \item Item 1\end{tabenumi} &
\begin{tabenumi}[resume*=table] \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.. 
                  \item More and more lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. \end{tabenumi}\\
\begin{tabenumi}[resume*=table] \item Perhaps this text could go on for a while too \end{tabenumi} & 
\begin{tabenumi}[resume*=table] \item Item 5 \end{tabenumi}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice answer! however, are necessary to define `after` twice: `after=\strut, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},` and `align=parleft,`.

Comment: @Zarko: Thank you. I have removed the superfluous options.

Comment: What is the code if I need the number of \enumitem to be restarted in every column?

Comment: @EnosLolang: You can use two different `series` and `resume` the corresponding one as in the following example:

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\toprule
Column 1 Heading & Column 2 Heading \\
\midrule
\begin{tabenumi}[series=tablefirst] \item Item 1\end{tabenumi} &
\begin{tabenumi}[series=tablesecond] \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.. 
                  \item More and more lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. \end{tabenumi}\\
\begin{tabenumi}[resume*=tablefirst] \item Perhaps this text could go on for a while too \end{tabenumi} & 
\begin{tabenumi}[resume*=tablesecond] \item Item 5 \end{tabenumi}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}`